# Remove flickering on resizing ajacent divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I use Twitter Bootstrap and JS to make a kind of sliding sidebar. When you click "Toggle", the selected column with "col-lg-1" expands to "col-lg-3" and "col-lg-10" shrinks to "col-lg-8" (with jQueryUI's `switchClass()` ). For animated effect on `show()` and `hide()` I use jQueryUI. But during animation and column resizing the contents of `#content` flicker (disappear and shown again when the animation is over).

HTML is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-1" id="menu-1">
    <a href="#">Toggle</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1" id="menu-1">
    <a href="#">Toggle</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-10" id="content">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cleaned JS is something like:

```
if ($col.hasClass('col-lg-3')){
  // hide on second click
  $col.switchClass('col-lg-3','col-lg-1');
  $content.switchClass('col-lg-8', 'col-lg-10');
}else{
  // open
  var $sibling = $bar.siblings('.col-lg-3');
  if($sibling.length == 1){
    // close sibling if it's open
    $sibling.switchClass('col-lg-3','col-lg-1');
  }
  $col.switchClass('col-lg-1','col-lg-3');
  $content.switchClass('col-lg-10', 'col-lg-8');
}
```

Could you suggest a fix? Or recommend another solution?

**UPD**:

- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duck/4uJuS/)
- Browser: Firefox 27.0.1

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ Also tell us in which browser the problem appears